# Connecting phone with RPi 0 W

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, pi-zero-w, hotspot

Can i host a hotspot on my RPi 0? So phones can connect to it and use the SSH from the pi.. 
Bluetooth would work too but my question is how and what do i need it for.

I searched a lot but there are complex ways like Blynx server (Java) that can't successfully run. It is getting to 100% CPU Limit and the console doesn't say anything but it should say Successfully started. While doing something on the RPi 0 in the background for a while gives a Message from syslogd@raspberrypi ... kernel:["Some Hexcodes"].
That's happening very often when i am trying to host a server on my Pi0 like Owncloud. Multiple times formated the SD card and only downloaded trusted packages.

Comment: Does one of the answers help you? If so, please accept one. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the RPi 0 W an Access Point so that any device using WiFi, e.g. your smart phone, can connect to it. You can also connect the RasPi to your local WiFi internet router so all devices that are connected to the RasPis Access Point can also get into internet.

This way you are using the RasPi as WiFi repeater. How to do it you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866).

Comment: I don't have a Wifi router that i can use. Except the open wifi. I need to use a password on it and then login but i don't have any interface right now so i want to connect my phone to the RasPi to use SSH.

Comment: @Gladox114 To configure a stand alone access point you can use both tutorials (linked by *Milliways* and my suggestion). When you are connected to the access point you are able to ssh into it and manage the RasPi.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Access Point on any model Pi.

There is a Foundation [Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) tutorial.

There are some limitations on Pi0W as it only has a single interface, so you will have no internet access.